# Python Index Out of Range list Exception handling

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have a list of Words in which i am trying to get previous and next four words of a certain index numbers. But in case if there does not exist previous or next word in words list, I get the error index out of range. I want to append 'NULL' keyword if word does not exist in Words list.
Here is my code:

```
A='Hello I have Used my beloved Belvu for gene and protein analysis and developed Matlab 
    visualize results'
from nltk import word_tokenize
Words=word_tokenize(A)
index = [6,14] # 6-index=Belvu, 14-index= Matlab



for ind in index:
    try:
        pn_words=[]  # previous four and next four words of mention
        pn_words.append(Words[ind-4])
        pn_words.append(Words[ind-3])
        pn_words.append(Words[ind-2])
        pn_words.append(Words[ind-1])
        pn_words.append(Words[ind+1])
        pn_words.append(Words[ind+2])
        pn_words.append(Words[ind+3])
        pn_words.append(Words[ind+4])
    except IndexError:
        pn_words.append('NULL')
    print(pn_words)
```

In above code, there exist two word after 'Matlab' ('visualize', 'results')in Words list. Since i am trying to get next four words to word 'Matlab', I want to have 'NULL' keyword if i call index out of range to words list. Similarly for previous four words, if word does not exist in Words list , i want NULL in place.How can i change my code to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word_tokenize` returns a simple list. You can add 4 time `'NULL'` (or `None` or whatever) in front and back and then slice the adjusted indexes:

```
A = '''Hello I have Used my beloved Belvu for gene and protein analysis and
        developed Matlab visualize results'''

from nltk import word_tokenize

Words = word_tokenize(A)
index = [6,14] # 6-index=Belvu, 14-index= Matlab

# padd your result list with 'NULL's
searched = ['NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'] + Words + ['NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'])

for i in index:
    # get the adjusted slice
    i += 4  # adjust i for the 4 added nulls in the beginning
    searched = searched[i-4:i] + seaerched[i+1:i+5]

    print(searched)
```

A slice does handle "overshooting" the list kindly - by adding 4 in front and back you will always get the NULLs you want.

Comment: Changed the code a bit to exclude the looked for word